# StepFunctionsLocal does not accept $$ parameter

Tags: aws-step-functions

As documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html), the AWS state machine definition syntax allows access to attributes from the higher scope within a map state iteration with `$$.Map.Item.Value`:

```
{
  "StartAt": "ExampleMapState",
  "States": {
    "ExampleMapState": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "Parameters": {
               "ContextValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
             },
      "Iterator": {
         "StartAt": "TestPass",
         "States": {
           "TestPass": {
             "Type": "Pass",    
             "End": true
           }
         }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

However, when run with the StepFunctionsLocal (both Java and Docker versions) this example definition itself raises SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED error:

```
SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: The value for the field 'ContextValue.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call at /States/ExampleMapState/Parameters
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug in the StepFunctionsLocal?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. Do validate your JSON structure [HERE](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) . You need map them properly.

Comment: @RanadipDutta, what makes you think that it is not valid JSON? It is the exact same example in the AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html under the Context Object Data for Map States title.

Comment: If you check in the json validator, there is an additional array index is something I roughly noticed but may be I am wrong. However, not here to argue or anything . Feel free to check once more.

Comment: @RanadipDutta, in case of invalid JSON, the StepFunctionsLocal raises INVALID_JSON_DESCRIPTION exception. The issue here is something else: SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED

Comment: Could you fix it @onurmatik ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your script to make sure you have properly escaped the double $$

Comment: What do you mean by properly escaping $$? Can you be more specific? What should be the correct version of the script? Did you try it? It is how it is done in the AWS's own example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, my best guess is that it's a bug in the `aws` cli (or a scaping issue when declaring the sfn definition, as stated [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QU5GqrlqgnQHmvC1llj0JBTg/step-function-local-accessing-context-object-causes-schema-validation-failed), though I wasn't able to do it).

Anyway, I tried `boto3` instead of the `cli` using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) example definition.

```
>>> definition = """
... {
...   "Comment": "Accessing context object in a state machine",
...   "StartAt": "Get execution context data",
...   "States": {
...     "Get execution context data": {
...       "Type": "Pass",
...       "Parameters": {
...         "startTime.$": "$$.Execution.StartTime",
...         "execName.$": "$$.Execution.Name"
...       },
...       "ResultPath": "$.executionContext",
...       "End": true
...     }
...   }
... }"""
>>> role = "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/DummyRole"
>>> r = client.create_state_machine(name="Test", definition=definition, roleArn=role)
>>> pprint.pprint(r)
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-length': '161',
                                      'date': 'Fri, 30 Dec 2022 19:46:31 GMT',
                                      'server': 'Jetty(9.4.43.v20210629)'},
                      'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                      'RetryAttempts': 0},
 'creationDate': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 30, 14, 46, 31, 770000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'stateMachineArn': 'arn:aws:states:us-west-2:123456789012:stateMachine:Test'}
```